# The tagged parameter in /search/advanced Stack Exchange API seems to be applying an AND condition instead of OR condition

Tags: bug, tags, search, stack-exchange, api

I'm trying to use the [Advanced Search API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) of Stack Exchange.

The documentation on that page says the `tagged` parameter should contain

> a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which at least one will be present on all returned questions.

This implies that the list of tags will be applied with an `OR` condition. But the list of tags is applying an `AND` condition, i.e. the questions in the results are containing all the tags instead of at least one of the tags.

Here is [a link to an example query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=javascript%3Bangularjs&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to demo the same, where the query requests for questions  tagged for `javascript` or `angularjs`, but the results contain only questions that have both the tags.

Answer (score 3):

This is [a long standing (documentation) bug](https://stackapps.com/questions/4157/parameter-tagged-in-search-advanced-seems-to-use-and-instead-of-or) and it has been ignored by both developers and up-voters for 3 and a half years now.  (And what kind of bug it is is debatable since at least a few of us prefer the AND behavior.)

Given the staying power of this bug, your only choice is to work around it.
One way is to:

1. Make multiple queries. For example, one for `javascript` then one for `angularjs`.
2. Then loop through the result sets and remove duplicates

There may be more efficient workarounds depending on your *exact* needs.